# Correct way to query on one-to-one relationship? (Laravel 7)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have two models in a one-to-one relationship: Person and PhoneNumber.

On the Person model, I define:

```
public function phone() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\PhoneNumber');
}
```

And on the phone number, I define:

```
public function person() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Person');
}
```

So that is how the one-to-one relationship is defined in the code.

Let's say the Person model contains columns with info about the person, for example, age. Meanwhile, the PhoneNumber may contain information such as whether or not it is a cell phone or landline.

What is the correct way, using Laravel best practices, to write a query that selects all people over the age of 65 who have a cell phone?

I know I could do something like this:

```
$results = Person::where('age', '>', 65)
             ->whereHas('phone_number', function($q) {
                 $q->where('type', 'cell');
             })->get();
```

However, this is just a plain query and doesn't take advantage of the hasOne/belongsTo relationship. My question is, is there a more idiomatic, simpler way to write the same query in Laravel?

Comment: `whereHas` does take advantage of the existence of the relationship which is why it needs to actually match what you named the relationship, in your case it should be `whereHas('phone'...` I am not sure I understand what the problem actually is though

Comment: Thanks, I was confused about how `whereHas` works. Your comment and the other has clarified it for me. For some reason I thought it had to take the table name and didn't need an existing relationship (for instance, I thought you could still use whereHas with `$database::table("something")` outside of Laravel? Where there are no models involved?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided is already making use of the relationship as you do not have to manually join the tables together nor specify what the foreign keys are, although I'm not sure why you wrote the relationship on the `whereHas` method as `phone_number` instead of `phone` as per the relationship definition code above. It should be:

```
$results = Person::where('age', '>', 65)
             ->whereHas('phone', function($q) {
                 $q->where('type', 'cell');
             })->get();
```

I do believe that in general, any kind of filtering that can be done in the database should be done in the database, otherwise if you want it to be done on the php side you can do it like this:

```
$results = Person::with('phone')->get()
             ->filter(function($p){
                 return $p->age > 65 && ($p->phone->type ?? '') === 'cell';
             });
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify how "any kind of filtering that can be done in the database should be done in the database" is relevant? That is what the whereHas is doing, right? I can't think of a situation where the filter() way would be preferred

Comment: @cheryllium yeah I was just implying your code I modified is generally the better option for you as filtering in database is more optimized. i.e. `filter()` after query is slower than filtering in the query